# How to migrate to Android Studio?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have been trying to create apps and games for android.

I started by learning the basics using eclipse.

But instead downloading the bundled android studio package i downloaded the stand alone sdk tools from this link http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Now many are saying that i should migrate to android studio,

So now should i download the bundled package from that link?(around 800 mb recommended in that link)

or the android studio ide only(around 200mb) in that link?

Can you please tell me which one should i download?

Comment: If you already have tne SDK installed, then you only need the Android Studio IDE, and not the bundle itself as you don't need a second copy of the SDK. You will just have to set the SDK path in Android Studio.

Comment: I had a slow connection and eclipse and SDK when I updated, but I still went with the larger download as I didn't want to be messing about with additional setup. I also wanted to archive my eclipse environment for reference and didn't want them to share an SDK location.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce there are two IDE only links. Which would you recommend?

Comment: Weston, so you mean you had the eclipse installed but you still downloaded the bundled package? Did it affect you in anyway?

Comment: Technically, if you have the space to download and install a second instance of the SDK on your PC, then if you want to make your life "simpler", then you can just grab the Bundled version which will work out of the box with no additional configuration, as @weston says. I guess that's the easier route.

Comment: No I haven't had any problems doing it that way. They keep themselves separated very well and don't interfere with one another in my experience.

Comment: One other point is my eclipse SDK has all the old SDK versions in it, my personal goal is to get to the point where all my projects run in android studio on SDK 21. At this point, I can expunge the whole eclipse install and it's large SDK repository.

Answer (score 0):

Both will work. Personally I chose to just get the bundle again because:

- I perceived there was a risk involved in additional setup.
- I could archive my eclipse environment.
- When I upgraded my projects to Android Studio, I wanted to enforce API 21, this is more obvious if the other APIs are not reachable from Android Studio.

Comment: I am worried if i get any problem as i already have the tools installed!

Comment: Don't worry, it will be fine.

Comment: Just during any setup, don't choose any locations that you used for eclipse. By default it places them in a separate place.

Comment: Ok,then i ll just install in the default c drive.Thanks

Comment: Some say it makes our pc slow,is it ok to have both eclipse and android studio in my pc? (Specs:2gb ram,2.2ghz dual core,windows xp)

Comment: Who said that? Well I'm surprised you get any work done on that machine, very poor specs, but it's not going to be any worse by keeping eclipse on, eclipse doesn't take up any resources when you're not using it other than HDD space.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think you can run Android Studio on XP. `Microsoft® Windows® 8/7/Vista/2003` required. http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements

Comment: I just saw that,so i think i have to upgrade my laptop.Should i try installing anyway?

Comment: I think that would be a waste of time, but I've got no way of knowing for sure.

Comment: I can't promise it will work well (you still have a poor machine after all), and you do so at your own risk, but the free option is to replace windows xp with linux. Do your research and back everything up. Drivers might be a problem for an older machine, make sure you look in to that.

Comment: However i am trying to get a new laptop maybe a mac.I ll be fine with eclipse  :)